# how to discover devices through Bonjour(Zeroconf) in Adobe Flex Mobile application for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, flex3, flash-builder, bonjour

I am writing an app in Adobe Flex framework targeted on iOS and Android platforms.
My app is suppose to 'talk' with other hardware devices on the network e.g. Printers, game consoles, computers etc.

I was vouching for Bonjour to do that for me. I found a native extension (.ane) for Bonjour [here](http://www.opentekhnia.com/?p=227)

The problem is this only works for iOS devices and not for android.

My questions: Is there any other way of achieving that for both platforms in Adobe Flex framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt find a method of doing it through Bonjour, but I found out a way...
Just install the UDP ane file to your project and you can make your own uPNP calls to the mutlicast ip address of your network on port 1900.
You can discovery devices and parse services in xml
here is the link to ane:
https://github.com/wouterverweirder/AIR-Mobile-UDP-Extension

best of luck!